# Recursive type properties in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I try to declare a recursive type with following interface

```
interface Map<T> {
  [key: string]: Map<T> | T;
}
```

However, when I try to get property of this object:

```
const map: Map<number> = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: 2
    }
  }
};

console.log(map.a.b.c);
```

I get an error:

```
TS2339:Property 'b' does not exist on type 'number | Map<number>'.  Property 'b' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

I understand why it happens, but is there a workaround?

P.S. My `tsconfig.json` is following:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Going off of this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html You will probably need to include a type assertion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An [indexable type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) isn't aware of what keys it has, so you cannot use the dot notation, instead, you'll need to use:

```
console.log(map["a"]["b"]["c"]);
```

Notice however that the type for `map["a"]["b"]` is `any`, you'll need to use `(map["a"] as MyMap<number>)["b"]` to get the right type.

You shouldn't be using the name `Map` for your interface because there's now a built-in type called [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) ([type definition](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L4818)).

If the example you posted really shows your use case then I suggest that you don't annotate the `map` variable at all:

```
const map = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: 2
        }
    }
};
console.log(map.a.b.c); // this is fine now
```

The compiler is smart enough to infer the type of `map` to:

```
type map = {
    a: {
        b: {
            c: number;
        }
    }
}
```